# Convert General to Date in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a date field where the format is (example) 20170101.
When I try to convert this field to short date, it comes up as "###".

I need the date in the format of 1/1/2017.

Can someone help?
Thanks!

Comment: does it still show `####` if you increase the size of the column?

Comment: Yes. It just increases the number of ### when I increase the column size.

Answer (score 1):

The data is not a date but a number and by simply changing the format will try to return a date that is 20,170,101 days from 1/1/1900.  And Excel stops recognizing dates after 12/31/9999.  This would be well beyond that, roughly 45 thousand years beyond that.

you can use a helper column with the following formula:

```
=--REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,7,0,"/"),5,0,"/")
```

Format it as desired.

Then you can copy paste just the value over the original.

[image]

Comment: So would you have used another -1 or would I have been honored by a +1 by the great @pnuts? :)

Comment: no sarcasm, I consider you opinion of high importance.  I may not always agree but I do consider it, and enjoy the debate.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did it.

Comment: @Pweshee please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.